# Flash builder 4.5 Grey background in Design Mode

Tags: linux, flash-builder, designmode

I just installed Flash builder 4.5 in my Kubuntu OS. I can created a new flex project in my eclipse. However, when I switched from source mode to design mode. The background is grey and doesn't show any components (nor the white background). I was wondering if you guys have solution for this. Thanks a lot.